# Can these two trees be identified by photo.

Tags: trees, tree-care

[image: tree1]

[image: tree2]

I would like know what these tree are. They are located in San Diego county California. The trees may not be native. Thanks, Jon.

Comment: Two different trees, two different questions. Please make a question for each tree.

Comment: The first looks like a cherry of some sort - the bark should be a bit shiny if it is. As for the second, looks as if its about to produce flowers - another photo when they open would be useful.

Comment: Second picture looks like an avocado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first tree looks like some variety of apricot to me.  The leaves are young, so have not quite reached their full size and shape, but here is a picture of mature leaves to compare.  [mature apricot leaves and fruit](http://carbonpilgrim.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/apricot.jpg)

I agree with WheelerWonka that the second tree is some form of Avocado.  The leaves are darker on your photo, [but the flowers look to be very similar](http://plant.daleysfruit.com.au/l/avocado-flowering-8948.jpeg).

It's been a while since you asked this question - have either of the trees put on any fruit since your post that could help us be sure we have identified them correctly?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I got about 10 avocado looking fruits growing on Tree 2. The suspect apricot tree did not produce any fruit. But it looks like it is under some stress, or half dead. Many of the branches which didn't produce leaves are still soft, so I am not sure if it is dead or dormant.